# Where in the fire code does it say gasoline may not be stored indoors?

Tags: code-compliance, fire-hazard

Re Seattle fire code, but site this applies to most U.S. cities.

I think it is forbidden to keep a fueled or formerly fueled gasoline generator indoors, esp in a commercial, multi tenant building.

But the code is so big, I don't know how to find the relevant rules.

Suggestions?

Comment: I suspect it's in the National Fire Protection Association code, probably volume 30 - Flammable and Combustible Liquids Code.  It's apparently accessible for free on the NFPA site, but you need to register to get to it.  http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards?mode=code&code=30

Answer (score 1):

Gasoline is allowed indoors. However, the occupancy then becomes H-2, and fire walls, ventilation, etc. are required. (See Section 307.4)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Seattle, WA fire code has recently been updated and will go into effect Jan. 1, 2017.  You may want to see the following website, which also lists the phone number to call.  [www.seattle.gov/firecode](http://www.seattle.gov/fire/FMO/firecode/firecode.htm)

[www.seattle.gov/fire code phone](http://www.seattle.gov/dpd/codesrules/codes/fire/)

Comment: Yes, that is the code, but I do not see (cannot find...) the section that would restrict storage of a gasoline generator in a house or office. How to locate that section?

Comment: The 2nd link gives a phone # to call with questions.  The # is:  (206) 684-8850.